# git behind proxy with user name and password

Tags: git, proxy, http-proxy, opensuse

In my development lab I have the following setup.

I have a proxy (with no password) through which I access the company code:

```
SO>cat ~/.ssh/config
Host my.company.net
    User git
    IPQoS throughput
    ProxyCommand nc -w 15 -X connect -x 10.26.192.28:3128 %h %p

#Host github.com
    #User git
    #ProxyCommand nc -w 5 -X connect -x 10.14.0.2:3128 %h %p


SO>
```

Initially we had a proxy with no password to access the Internet.
The problem that I'm facing now is the fact that due to security concerns that proxy is now password protected and I can no longer use the same way to access the git repository from github/gitlab etc.

To put it in another words, the commented lines used to work, now they no longer do due to the proxy password.

Environment details are below:

```
SO>cat /etc/os-release | grep -i pretty
PRETTY_NAME="openSUSE Leap 15.5"
SO>rpm -qf `which nc`
netcat-openbsd-1.203-150400.1.5.x86_64
SO>git --version
git version 2.35.3
SO>
```

Thanks in advance for any proper suggestion - yes, I looked at some other similar questions but couldn't find any of them usable to my particular case.

Comment: Does [.netrc](https://www.gnu.org/software/inetutils/manual/html_node/The-_002enetrc-file.html) help?

Comment: @ElpieKay, I've tried but netcat doesn't seem to use ~/.netrc (I've done a strace and no access to ~/.netrc file could be found in the strace)

Comment: https://adangel.org/2020/10/15/github-behind-proxy/ "*Solution 3 (proxy with auth, using ncat)*" instead of `nc`; `nc` seems to be unable to authenticate at proxy. "*Solution 4 (proxy with auth, using socat)*".

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/447780/ssh-through-authentication-requiring-proxy

Comment: ncat doesn't work with authenticated proxy, but works with proxy without authentication.

Comment: @INS It does: `ncat --proxy-type http --proxy 10.26.192.28:3128 --proxy-auth proxyuser:password`